# What design pattern should I employ for validating character movement?

Tags: java, movement, tilemap, rpg

I'm developing a RPG in Java and have a Map class, which will contain all the MapObjects (the Player, Enemies, Walls, etc.):

Map.java

```
public class Map {

private int width;
private int height;

private ArrayList<MapObject> MapObjects = new ArrayList<MapObject>();

public Map(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
 }
```

Hero.java:

```
public class Hero extends MapObject implements Movable {

private Map map;

public Hero(int x, int y, int direction, Map map) {
    super(x, y, direction);
    this.map = map;
}

public boolean move(int direction) {
    //movement code
}

}
```

I will have a listener on an external class that will call the hero.move(direction) function.

What is the best approach to validate the movement (making sure that there's an empty space on the map)?

I could pass the Map as an argument, or even use the Command design pattern (the hero being the "remote" and the map being the implementation and executer), but I'm not sure if any of those are the right way to approach this problem.

Comment: When I make games I try to avoid doing things the right way, because where is the fun in that?

Comment: Why not give the map a method that returns if a zone is empty or not `map.is_free(x,y,width,height)`? And the player asks the map if he can move. I don't completly understand "the map being the implementation and executer" maybe that's what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to over-complicate or over-engineer your code by using design patterns as solution templates. Design patterns exist primarily as a means of communicating about a design efficiently. You should not think about problems in terms like "which design pattern do I use to solve this?" but rather "*what do I do* to solve this?" If what you do ends up aligning in some ways to a common pattern, great. But by limiting yourself only to choices considered design patterns you drastically reduce your solution search space.

In this case, you need something so simple it doesn't really have a "design pattern" associated with it. You need:

- the map object to be able to tell you if a given tile is passable
- your hero movement function to check if the tile the hero is going to move to is passable by asking the map (since it's already a member of the hero class).

That's all. Nice and simple. Keep your solutions simple and add generality as complexity increases; don't start with something more involved that it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

Design patters aren't used (mostly) to solve implementation problems. They are there to keep the code flexible and easy to maintain an change. Like others said, simply add a method that checks if that spot is empty and there is a clear path from the current spot to the destination. The question you should ask is how to implement the check in O(1). You probably should start by placing the items on the map in a grid instead of an ArrayList.